# Is it possiblle to get and pass the socket id in jmeter which changes on runtime

Tags: socket.io, jmeter

I am using a static URL initially, which runs fine until the socket id gets updated in the URL, the socket id is generated by the application and I am not able to figure out the way to get it, because that is the only thing getting modified after a page refresh and other activities.
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Fetching it from network data(UI) will make no sense as I need to perform Load Testing, Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use websocket samplers and get the socketID using a post processor and pass it in the Http request dynamically ${socketID}.

Reference [LINK](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)